# yesod/hamlet: what happens on the right hand side of "$forall <-" ?

Tags: haskell, yesod

The manual http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates just says "looping over lists - we got you covered". I don't understand the exact semantics of "list" in that statement.

It is not "arbitrary haskell expression of type `[something]`": I cannot write

```
main = putStrLn $  renderHtml [shamlet|
 <ul> 
   $forall x <- reverse [ False, True ]
     <li>#{x}
|]
```

It seems it must be a literal list (in square brackets, elements separated by commas) but what exactly are valid list elements?

It could be numeric literals - at least the following makes it through splicing

```
main = putStrLn $  renderHtml [shamlet|
 <ul> 
   $forall x <- [ 0, 1 ]
     <li>#{ x }
|]
```

but then the compiler does not like it because (I think) numeric literals are polymorphic.
The usual fix is to put a type signature somewhere. But where?

Comment: I am not an expert, and I do not know the precise answer. Nevertheless, it would not surprise me if the only thing you could put after the `<-` was a variable name.

Comment: I have never used the Shakespearean DSLs, but I think that the problem relies in the parsing: instead of `#{ x }`, try `#{x}` as all Yesod's examples—i.e., trim the spaces.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Always using `forall` with interpolated variable set in handler.

Comment: OK, using a variable is fine, and it also gives a place to put the type annotation, as in `let bs = [1 :: Int .. 10] in defaultLayout [whamlet| $forall x <- bs  #{x} |]` (with a line break before `#` that I don't know how to write in SO mini-markdown)

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I found the relevant place in the source code ( https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare/blob/master/hamlet/Text/Hamlet/Parse.hs#L209 ) and the thing behind `<-` comes from `parseDeref` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20263640/2868481

What is this `Data.Char.isSymbol` anyway? FYI,

```
import Data.Char
filter isSymbol [toEnum 0 .. toEnum 127]    ==>  "$+<=>^`|~"
```

I wonder whether that's intended behaviour (for hamlet/yesod).

Comment: The first link is broken.