# $if expressions in Hamlet

Tags: haskell, if-statement, hamlet

I have a condition in my Hamlet template that looks like this:

```
    $if (&&) (index == 0) (row == 0)
```

which works fine. If I try to re-write this as the more natural

```
    $if (index == 0) && (row == 0)
```

or

```
    $if ((index == 0) && (row == 0))
```

then it doesn’t parse. The error message is:

> Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
>
> unexpected "&"
>
> expecting ")"

This is puzzling; does it support some binary operators but not others?

What are the rules governing what kinds of expressions can be used in an `$if` statement in Hamlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed I don't see that this is defined in the Yesod book or in the API docs.

Your best bet is to read the source, e.g. https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare/blob/master/hamlet/Text/Hamlet/Parse.hs#L458

I think the item directly after `$if` comes from
`parseDeref` https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare/blob/master/shakespeare/Text/Shakespeare/Base.hs#L96

indeed your observation can be isolated (type this in ghci):

```
import Text.Shakespeare.Base
import Test.Parsec

parse parseDeref "source" "(a && b)"

    Left "source" (line 1, column 4):
    unexpected "&"
    expecting ")"

parse parseDeref "source" "(&&) a b"

    Right (DerefBranch (DerefBranch (DerefIdent (Ident "&&")) (DerefIdent (Ident "a"))) (DerefIdent (Ident "b")))
```

Ultimately, the parser calls `Data.Char.isSymbol`, and to my surprise,

```
isSymbol '='   ==> True
isSymbol '&'   ==> False
```

Comment: Interesting. That’s a massive bug. `isSymbol` returns characters in the Unicode category *Symbol*. Many operators, including `&`, `/` and `?` are in the Unicode category *Punctuation* though. Thanks for digging that up.

Comment: Links are broken.